# Best way to make display sports ranking in a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am making an iPhone App for upcoming FIFA world cup 2014 and need to make "Groups & Standings" score table. Here is so far I have made.

[image: screen shot]

And the code for this is simple (but not completed yet) :

```
if (index==0) {
    label.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"GROUP - %d", index+1];

    UITextView *text1 = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 90, 260, 20)]; 
    text1.text = @"TEAM \t\t MP \t W \t D \t L \t GF \t GA \t Pts";
    text1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:10];
    text1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [imgView addSubview:text1];

    UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 90, 260, 20)];
    label1.text = @"label \t one";
    label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    //[imgView addSubview:label1];
}

else if (index==1) {
    label.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"GROUP - %d", index+1];
    UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 20)];
    label2.text = @"label two";
    label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [imgView addSubview:label2];
}
```

All the data will be coming from XML file hosted in my server. I do not need to parsing them as I will be using external classes to parse data. I only want to know what would be the best way to develop this score board.

My score board will be something like this:

```
TEAM                            MP    W    D    L    GF    GA    Pts

[country1.png] Argentina        3     3    0    0     7     1     9

[country2.png] Korea Republic   3     1    1    1     5     6     4

[country3.png] Greece           3     1    0    2     2     5     3

[country4.png] Nigeria          3     0    1    2     3     5     1
```

Please note that: all these data (numbers and those .png images) are from server and I already had handled them to store in an `NSMutableArray`. I just need to display them as shown in the above score table and the screen shot of the simulator is what I have done so far.

Anyone can tell me the best way to handle/display those data efficiently?

Comment: You should precise where your code comes from. Is it from *viewForHeaderInSection:* ?

Comment: I have the parsed data and have stored in some mutable arrays. I have to use them to display. I can display the data as
    UILabel *countryA = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 90, 260, 20)];
    countryA.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [myArray objectAtIndex:index]];
or something like this ... I want to know what will be the best and most efficient way to make this. I have lots of mutable array which are storing those individual data.

Comment: You have an answer now that you seem happy with - if so it's customary to select it.

Comment: David, I just completed this and for that I had to create some arrays. But, its working perfectly for me now. All your four options are great and I will keep those in my mind. Thanks a lot :-) and yeah I am closing this issue and choosing you answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ideas:

1) search for an open source spreadsheet or multicolumn class

2) use an NSAttributedString with tab stops or other fixed spacing for each line, the text portion. This would be my preferred solution, but you'll spend some time figuring it out.

3) create a template UITableviewCell subclass, and use a UIImageView for the image on the left, then one UILabel per text item. Each item abuts other items on the left and right. You may find this the easiest solution.

4) there are a few HTML open source classes that take HTML input and generate attributed strings for you - see Cocanetics web site for one.

5) turn your data into an HTML table and render it in a UIWebView.

Comment: I've made a sports app, and went for the 3rd option. It's pretty easy. I did exactly what you suggested and it works flawlessly. I'd go with that solution.

Comment: Hi David and rdurand, thanks for your answers.
@David: Hi David, I liked all your ideas but that also made me confused which one to go with. Do you know any tutorial links of your suggestion number "4"? I want to know how to do that.

Comment: Well, if you can figure out how to do the html, just look on SO for code that shows you how to load a html file (or string) into a UIWebView. There is a lot of that code around.